# android how to add two views into an activity

Tags: android

I wanna add one xml file and one class which extends View to an single activity so that it work simultaneously.
like below,

1. main.xml
2. private static class GraphicsView extends View

**MyActivity**

```
onCreate()
{
 RelativeLayout ll= new RelativeLayout(this);
ll.addView(new GraphicsView(this));
ll.--------->how to add main.xml here?
 setContentView(ll);// so that i can write like this
}
```

please solve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use layout inflater.  Do some thing like this....

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adapterContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xmls, null);
```

Now add this view to ll.

ll.addView(view)...

Thanks.